# Ajax message after node save

Tags: hooks, ajax, updating, status-messages

I am trying to add a Ajax Alert or popup message inside a hook_node_presave or hook_node_update, but it is not working.

My current code look like this, but I have tried a lot of other ajax

```
$response = new ajaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new AlertCommand('Ajax test'));
return $response;
```

The node is saved but no alert and no errors in the console.
Drupal 9

Comment: Those hooks dont return responses. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/9.2.x

Comment: No I understand that now.
I do have a RedirectResponse that works fine when I not saving with Ajax.

Comment: Any suggestion to how I can solve this issue?
I have struggled with this for 3 days now.
Everything works fine when savning from a form. Then I get at message on the page. 
But when saving with Ajax I want at alert or someting to popup.